# Why are my images not being displayed correctly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using CSS& Html to make my E-Portfolio.

I have a div class titled "language__list" which contains 8 images. The goal is to use flexbox to align them in 2 rows of 4. However my issue has been, the images have been shrinking when applying my code (will list). The first image will be displayed at an appropriate size but the next image will be significantly decreased in size and the pattern continues till you can't see the next image.

Comment: where I can See, Add Some HTML & CSS code Here

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.